# xsp source install missing files CentOS

Tags: mono, centos, installation, xsp

I installed xsp from source but get this error when testing

```
$ xsp4 --port 9000
Handling exception type FileNotFoundException
Message is Could not load file or assembly 'xsp4, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies
IsTerminating is set to True
Could not load file or assembly 'xsp4, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies
  at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (string,string)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (string,string)
  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost (System.Type hostType, System.String virtualDir, System.String physicalDir) <0x41cf8ca0 + 0x00ba4> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.VPathToHost.CreateHost (Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer server, Mono.WebServer.WebSource webSource) <0x41cf7ce0 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.DebugMain (System.String[] args, Boolean root, IApplicationHost ext_apphost, Boolean quiet) <0x41c98770 + 0x0084f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.DebugMain (System.String[] args) <0x41c981a0 + 0x00117> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.Main (System.String[] args) <0x41c97d50 + 0x00027> in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'xsp4, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies
File name: 'xsp4, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'
  at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (string,string)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (string,string)
  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost (System.Type hostType, System.String virtualDir, System.String physicalDir) <0x41cf8ca0 + 0x00ba4> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.VPathToHost.CreateHost (Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer server, Mono.WebServer.WebSource webSource) <0x41cf7ce0 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.DebugMain (System.String[] args, Boolean root, IApplicationHost ext_apphost, Boolean quiet) <0x41c98770 + 0x0084f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.DebugMain (System.String[] args) <0x41c981a0 + 0x00117> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.Main (System.String[] args) <0x41c97d50 + 0x00027> in <filename unknown>:0
```

So I did the recommended strace to get more info:

```
$ strace -e trace=open xsp4
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)     = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/local/bin/xsp4", O_RDONLY)   = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/bin/mono", O_RDONLY)         = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/mono/config", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/home/ultron/.mono/config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/dev/shm/mono.4290", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC, 0640) = 3
open("/proc/self/maps", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/proc/self/maps", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/xsp4.exe.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/xsp4.exe", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.4.0.mscorlib/0.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/policy.4.0.mscorlib.dll", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/mono/assemblies/mscorlib/mscorlib.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/proc/self/maps", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/proc/self/maps", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/proc/self/task/4292/comm", O_RDWR) = 3
open("/dev/null", O_RDWR)               = 3
open("/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/xsp4.exe", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/xsp4/4.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/xsp4.exe.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/xsp4/4.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/xsp4.exe.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/xsp4.exe.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/xsp4.exe.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/xsp4/4.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/xsp4.exe.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/mono/assemblies/xsp4/xsp4.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/xsp4.exe", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/xsp4/4.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/xsp4.exe.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/xsp4/4.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/xsp4.exe.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/xsp4.exe.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/xsp4.exe.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/xsp4/4.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/xsp4.exe.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/xsp4/4.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/xsp4.exe.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.0.4.Mono.WebServer2/0.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/policy.0.4.Mono.WebServer2.dll", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/Mono.WebServer2.dll", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.WebServer2/0.4.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.WebServer2.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.WebServer2/0.4.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.WebServer2.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/Mono.WebServer2.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/Mono.WebServer2.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/Mono.WebServer2/0.4.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.WebServer2.dll.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/mono/assemblies/Mono.WebServer2/Mono.WebServer2.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.4.0.Mono.Security/0.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/policy.4.0.Mono.Security.dll", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/Mono.Security.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/Mono.Security.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/mono/assemblies/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.4.0.System/0.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/policy.4.0.System.dll", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/mono/assemblies/System/System.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.4.0.System.Core/0.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/policy.4.0.System.Core.dll", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.Core.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.Core.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Core/System.Core.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.4.0.System.Configuration/0.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/policy.4.0.System.Configuration.dll", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.Configuration.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.Configuration.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Configuration/System.Configuration.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.4.0.System.Xml/0.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/policy.4.0.System.Xml.dll", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.Xml.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.Xml.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Xml/System.Xml.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/mono/4.5/machine.config", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/proc/uptime", O_RDONLY)          = 4
open("/etc/mono/4.5/machine.config", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)          = 3
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.4.0.System.Web/0.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/policy.4.0.System.Web.dll", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Web/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Web/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Web/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.Web.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.Web.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Web/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Web/System.Web.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/ultron/web.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/mono/4.5/machine.config", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/Mono.Security.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/Mono.Security.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/xsp4/4.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/xsp4.exe", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Web/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Web/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.Web.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.Web.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.Configuration.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.Configuration.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.Core.dll.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/aot-cache/amd64/System.Core.dll.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/mono/4.5/machine.config", O_RDONLY) = 5
open("/etc/mono/4.5/machine.config", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/etc/mono/4.5/web.config", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/etc/mono/4.5/web.config", O_RDONLY) = 5
open("/etc/mono/4.5/settings.map", O_RDONLY) = 5
open("/home/ultron/web.config", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/policy.4.2.xsp4/0.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/policy.4.2.xsp4.dll", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/xsp4/4.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/xsp4.dll", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/xsp4.dll", O_RDONLY)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/4.5//Facades/xsp4.dll", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/gac/xsp4/4.2.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/xsp4.exe", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/xsp4.exe", O_RDONLY)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/4.5//Facades/xsp4.exe", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/4.5/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/4.5/libc.so.6.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/4.5/libc.so.6.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/mono/4.5/libc.so.6.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libc.so.6.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libc.so.6.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libc.so.6.so.la", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY)        = 5
open("/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm", O_RDONLY) = 5
Handling exception type FileNotFoundException
Message is Could not load file or assembly 'xsp4, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies
IsTerminating is set to True
Could not load file or assembly 'xsp4, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies
  at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (string,string)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (string,string)
  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost (System.Type hostType, System.String virtualDir, System.String physicalDir) <0x40c874b0 + 0x00ba4> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.VPathToHost.CreateHost (Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer server, Mono.WebServer.WebSource webSource) <0x40c864f0 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.DebugMain (System.String[] args, Boolean root, IApplicationHost ext_apphost, Boolean quiet) <0x40c2d770 + 0x0084f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.DebugMain (System.String[] args) <0x40c2d1a0 + 0x00117> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.Main (System.String[] args) <0x40c2cd50 + 0x00027> in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'xsp4, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies
File name: 'xsp4, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756'
  at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (string,string)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:CreateInstanceAndUnwrap (string,string)
  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost (System.Type hostType, System.String virtualDir, System.String physicalDir) <0x40c874b0 + 0x00ba4> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.VPathToHost.CreateHost (Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer server, Mono.WebServer.WebSource webSource) <0x40c864f0 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.DebugMain (System.String[] args, Boolean root, IApplicationHost ext_apphost, Boolean quiet) <0x40c2d770 + 0x0084f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.DebugMain (System.String[] args) <0x40c2d1a0 + 0x00117> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.Main (System.String[] args) <0x40c2cd50 + 0x00027> in <filename unknown>:0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

But I don't understand the source of all these missing files problems.
Previously I'd tried the path described in mono-project.com with using yum and module mono-xsp4 but had
the same error upon testing. So used yum to uninstall that module and tried the source install method instead.

Has anyone installed this version of the sources on CentOS 7?

I used these instructions for the source install:
[gist.github](https://gist.github.com/andreazevedo/9479518)

Using CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) with 
GCC version 5.4.0

```
$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.4.2 (Stable 4.4.2.11/f72fe45 Fri Jul 29 09:49:37 UTC 2016)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem a few days ago. You're running XSP4 from the command line, and that is just a driver program. It needs to find the DLL, Mono.WebServer.dll.
That DLL needs to be in the GAC, or you need to use MONO_PATH=. assuning the DLL is in the same folder.

See
https://linux.die.net/man/1/mono

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable answer. So I'm accepting it. But probably won't have the time to verify it.